# Bar chart with vertical lines in each bar

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Is there any way how I could draw the following chart with Chart.js? I went through the documentation but didn't find anything similar... The closest would be probably multi-axis bar chart

[image: chart]

Thanks for any kind of help!

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a bar chart with error bars. Checkout this plugin. 
   https://www.npmjs.com/package/chartjs-plugin-error-bars

Comment: @John Thanks for the suggestion! It's not exactly what I need, there are only 2 values (min, max) but i need a third one and there's no way of customising how it looks, but it's closer than anything else so I'll try to adapt it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I went for a custom chart type following the guide here: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/charts.html